# why does sql = FALSE always return true

Tags: mysql, sql

No matter what I do in MySQL 5.0 such as

```
SELECT 'test' = FALSE

SELECT '' = FALSE
```

I always get a 1 back in SQL. What is the reason for that?  I was expecting a 0 or FALSE

**EDIT** adding context to the questions.
This is how the problem came about, it happened that $name inadvertently became false making this join always pass, then I wondered why this works.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM user a 
INNER JOIN inventory b ON b.user_id = a.id AND b.name = $name
```

Comment: I think you need to describe what you are trying to do. This is nonsensical as it stands.

Comment: I'm editing the question to add some context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySql [FALSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/boolean-literals.html) is a constant literal which is always evaluated as 0.

So you are checking if `'test' = 0` or if `'' = 0`, and since you are comparing a string with an integer, MySql will try to cast the string to an integer.

If you try this query:

```
SELECT 'test' = FALSE
```

it will return 1 (TRUE) because 'test' will be converted to 0, while if you try this:

```
SELECT '1test' = FALSE
```

it will return 0 (FALSE) because '1test' will be converted to 1.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with MySQL's [implicit conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) when using comparison operators (i.e. `=`)

Taken from the docs:

> Strings are automatically converted to numbers and numbers to strings as necessary.

So, in your case:

- `'test'` gets converted to `0`
- `FALSE` is `0`
- `0 = 0` is `TRUE`.